# Why is & tokenized as "&amp;" in Python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

When trying to use the Toktok word tokenizer from NLTK in Python3

```
string='&& Test & and L&R '
from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
ToktokTokenizer().tokenize(string)
```

I obtain the following output:

```
['&&amp;', 'Test', '&amp;', 'and', 'L&R']
```

Looks like it escapes the & in a strange way.
I'm using NLTK version 3.3 and Python 3.6.4.

Any guess why this happens and an efficient way of solving it?
I know I can go through the answer with

```
[tok.replace("&amp;","&") for tok in tokenized_sentence]
```

but it seems a dirty hack. I would like to know if there is a way of not producing this effect in the first way.

Comment: The [source](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/toktok.html) just states that ampersand is a "problematic character" but doesn't explain why.  I don't think there's a way to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @snakecharmerb for the `&` the source states:

```
# Replace problematic character with numeric character reference.
```

One approach to solve the issue is to override the fields on the `ToktokTokenizer` instance, for example:

```
import re

from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer

string = '&& Test & and L&R '

tokenizer = ToktokTokenizer()
tokenizer.AMPERCENT = re.compile('& '), '& '
tokenizer.TOKTOK_REGEXES = [(regex, sub) if sub != '&amp; ' else (re.compile('& '), '& ') for (regex, sub) in
                            ToktokTokenizer.TOKTOK_REGEXES]

result = tokenizer.tokenize(string)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['&&', 'Test', '&', 'and', 'L&R']
```